# Vue property not updating as excpected in v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

`queryString` is a property bound to an input with `v-model`.

I have a component that listens to an event-bus and should override `queryString` property value. While I can successfully receive and print the `result` variable, for some reason `queryString` value isn't updated. Am I doing something wrong?

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      queryString: '',
    }
  },

  mounted(){
    this.$nuxt.$on("result-selected", function(result){
      console.log("the result " + result)
      this.queryString = result
    })
  },
}
```